TikZ Tree Image
I recently figured out how to use tikz trees, so filling in a potential rectangle and the rest would not be an issue. Is there a way to somehow create a tree looking like the image provided that is not messy?
\begin{tikzpicture}             [           
level 1/.style={level distance = 4cm, sibling distance = 3cm},          
level 2/.style={level distance = 2cm, sibling distance = 3cm},              
grow=left,              
edge from parent fork left          %   every node/.append style = {draw, anchor = west}    
]   
\node[draw]{\footnotesize text here         
} child {node[draw] {\footnotesize text here}} child {node[draw]{ \footnotesize text here}};    
\end{tikzpicture}


welcome! can you provide code for an example we can compile to show what you've tried? what do you mean by 'not messy'? the image isn't a tree. I'd try schemata, maybe?

hi! Thank you very much, I have tried the left? side
\begin{tikzpicture}    [     level 1/.style={level distance = 4cm, sibling distance = 3cm},    level 2/.style={level distance = 2cm, sibling distance = 3cm},     grow=left,     edge from parent fork left    % every node/.append style = {draw, anchor = west}     ]     \node[draw]{\footnotesize text here     } child {node[draw] {\footnotesize text here}} child {node[draw]{ \footnotesize text here}};    \end{tikzpicture}
I will take a look at the schemata option thank you

you can use the edit button (which doesn't look like a button) at the bottom left of your question to edit your question.
